# how to connect ssrs to visual c# express using reportviewer with subreport

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportviewer, firebird

I've been searching the web for some time now but I couldn't find an article relating with my problem. 
I am using C# express 2012, with reportbuilder 3.0 installed as a report development and reportviewer. I am using firebird as my database. 
I can generate normal simple reports with no problem on my computer and on the deployed computer.

```
 select * from tbl_sample
```

My problem now is how do I implement subreports?

I have been reading materials regarding ssrs but I can't connect my report with ssrs. Am I missing something?

I have read that visual studio supports ssrs add on but I can't seem to find how to activate it on my machine.

What do I need to download? How to activate ssrs instance or service? How do I connect ssrs to report builder?
How do I include ssrs in the package deployment for the client to use reports with subreports?

Any information is welcome.

Comment: check this - `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6999/Creating-Reports-with-SQL-Reporting-Service-and-Vi`

Comment: thank you for the information. My dilemma now is I don't use SQL Server 2000 with SP3. any other method how do I install ssrs?

Comment: I hope you are aware that 1) the current version of SQL Server is 2014, and 2) SSRS requires a rather hefty licensing fee.

Comment: yes I am fully aware that ssrs requires a license that's why I am using MS sql 2012 which is I think is free for the ssrs database. I am using for ssrs SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU which is also free. What I now require is how to connect to my c# code programmatically to ssrs server. another problem is how to connect my database to the ssrs server as a datasource of the report. The thing is I'm using an another database aside from mssql using odbc.